# Order by comma separated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables body_part and video_customised.

Table ->  **body_part**

```
+-----+-----------|
| id  | title     |  
------------------|
| 1     Abs
| 2     Chest
| 3     Neck
------------------
```

Table -> **video_customised**

```
+-----+-----------|
| id  | body_part |  
------------------|
| 1     2,1,3     |
------------------|
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT  vc.body_part  ,
  GROUP_CONCAT(bp.name ORDER BY vc.body_part) 
 as body_part_name FROM 
 `video_customised` `vc`
LEFT JOIN `body_part` as `bp` ON 
  `FIND_IN_SET`(bp.id, vc.body_part);
```

**Result**

```
+-----+-----------------------|
| body_part  | body_part_name |  
------------------------------|
| 2,1,3         Abs,Chest,Neck|     
------------------------------|
```

**Expected Result:**

```
+-----+-----------------------|
| body_part  | body_part_name |  
------------------------------|
| 2,1,3         Chest,Abs,Neck|     
------------------------------|
```

I want to GROUP_CONCAT body_part_name, its order should be same as body_part.

Comment: Database design mistake! Use a link table instead of comma seperated lists of keys

Comment: You really need to normalize your data. This is neither scalable or maintainable.

Comment: I know @RiggsFolly,@JaY, You have the solution please give.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fix your data model.  You should not be storing lists of numbers in a single field.  Why?

- In SQL tables, a column should contain a single value.
- Numeric values should be stored as *numbers* not *strings*.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined.
- SQL has relatively poor string processing capabilities.
- SQL is not designed to optimize queries on strings.

You should be using a junction/association table, with one row per body part and per video.

That said, sometimes we are stuck with other peoples really, really, really bad design decisions.  In such a case, you can do what you want using `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT vc.body_part,
       GROUP_CONCAT(bp.name ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(bp.id, vc.body_part)) as body_part_names
FROM video_customised vc LEFT JOIN
     body_part bp
     ON FIND_IN_SET(bp.id, vc.body_part); 
GROUP BY vc.body_part;
```